# How Can I place a Line Break while writing to a file

Tags: c++, windows, file-io

I am creating a configuration file on click of a button by the following code.

```
fputs(  "AutoStart = " +strAutoWinStart + 
        "AutLogHistory = " +strAutoLogSvrHistory + 
        "AutoScan= " +strAutoScanDetect + 
        "AutoMount = "+ strAutoMount + 
        "AutoOpen = "+ strAutoOpenWin + 
        "LastConnectedSvr = "+ strAutoDetLastConSvr,pFile);
```

and the Output file looks as below:

> AutoStart = 1AutLogHistory = 0AutoScan= 1AutoMount = 0AutoOpen = 1LastConnectedSvr = 0

Instead I need my output should have a line break in each parameter and look as below:

> AutoStart = 1
>   AutLogHistory = 0
>   AutoScan= 1
>   AutoMount = 0
>   AutoOpen = 1
>   LastConnectedSvr = 0

Comment: Is that really your code?  `fputs` takes a `const char*` to be written to the file.  Either your `strName` variables are of some string class type (which is required to be able to concatenate them using `+`) or they are string literals (which is required to be able to pass them to `fputs`).  They can't be both.

Comment: @ James McNellis, Yes my strName variables are stringclass type and I am concatenating them using +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "\r\n" (or "\n" for UNIX-style linefeeds) to create a new line in the file.

Some editors on Windows such as Notepad don't handle UNIX-style linefeeds well, showing everything on one line. For the most portability across operating systems, use "\n". For the most usability in Windows, use "\r\n".

Even better: use std::ofstream with std::endl - your question is tagged C++ after all.

Comment: The C++ IOStreams library performs line ending translation so that writing `\n` to a text-mode stream results in the platform line ending being written to the stream.  Do the C I/O functions not do this translation?

Comment: @James: to my understanding they *can*, but they are not *required* to - how the newline is represented externally is outside the scope of the spec. Could have easily mis-interpreted though.