# How to add a break to a line while writing to a text file

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add a line break in a text file but nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
void controleformules::on_pushButton_4_clicked(
{
 QString str= ui->textEdit_2->toPlainText();

 QString filename= str+".txt";

 QFile file( filename );

 if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) )
 {

    QTextStream stream( &file );

      stream
              << "U heeft nu deze 2 formules gekozen: Formule 1: " << x1Int << " + " << y1Int << " = " << r1Int << ". Formule 2: "<< x2Int << " + " << y2Int << " = " << r2Int << "." << '\n'
              <<"eerst moet je in beide formules de x of de y elimeneren, wij doen de y eerst";
   }
}
```

I tried both `"\n"` and `'\n'`,

I hope someone can help me,

Thanks in advance Tim Smits

Comment: See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181630/how-can-i-place-a-line-break-while-writing-to-a-file

If you're using windows, you'll need "\r\n"

Comment: Check what "\n" means.

Comment: How are you looking at the text file?  Does the character really not get output, or is your reader just ignoring it?

Comment: It is “text”, not “tekst” :)

Comment: @lan THank you, I already saw that post but i didnt take the time to read it fully, that was my bad. It works.

Comment: @Ian - unless `QTextStream` is a **binary** stream, you don't need `"\r\n"`. `'\n'` is a newline character, and text streams translate it into whatever is needed to create a new line.

Comment: How about using `std::endl` instead of `\n`?

Comment: I tried your code and it prints line ending like expected. Make sure you look in the correct file. (remove it and run program again to make sure it gets written in)

Comment: @PeteBecker Based on the fact that he said it now works, I'm assuming that the \n was getting written directly and whatever text editor was being used to check the file is a windows program that doesn't handle unix style line breaks (like notepad)

Comment: @user2479441: By explicitly writing `"\r\n"` on Windows you are simply sweeping the problem under the carpet: you are fixing the symptoms of the problem, not the problem itself. What you really have to do is open the file in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your underlying `QIODevice` (the file) is not really working in text mode. Use `QIODevice::Text` when opening the file that is used with the stream

```
QFile file( filename , QIODevice::Text );
...
QTextStream stream( &file);
```

For a text stream, both `"\n"` and `'\n'` should work. You may opt for `std::endl` (or, more precisely, its counterpart in Qt) instead, but this is not really necessary. `"\n"` and `'\n'` will produce proper result regardless of the OS, assuming your output stream is indeed a *text* stream, and assuming that your generate file on the same platform that you use to inspect it. (The remarks asserting that `"\r\n"` *must* be used on Windows are incorrect.)

An example of a situation when you indeed will have to use `"\r\n"` is when you are trying to generate a Windows text file on a POSIX system.

Comment: `QTextStream` is _the text stream_. It even has no constrctor that accepts both `QFile` and `QIODevice::OpenMode`

Comment: @Lol4t0: It is a "text stream" in a sense that its formatting interface is designed for working with textual data. It is **not** a text stream in C++ sense of the term (by default). In order to be a text stream in that sense it has to be explicitly opened with `QIODevice::Text` open mode.

Comment: can you provide any reference? Again, your code wouldn't compile, as QTextStream has no acceptable constructor.

Comment: @Lol4t0: I was misled by an example at the link. I corrected the code. As for the effects of `QIODevice::Text`, the [informal] description can be found here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtextstream.html. "Note: On Windows, all '\n' characters are written as '\r\n' if QTextStream's device or string is opened using the QIODevice::Text flag."